# Hive table text file upload special characters

Tags: hiveql

I have a pipe delimited text file that I'm trying to create a Hive external table from. However in COL_2 for a particular value (d’Algerie) the ’ character is getting replaced by a box, i.e. d�Algerie. I've tried some of the online solutions such as:

```
ALTER TABLE pi_aarrepos_analysis.tbl_input_accounts SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='GBK');
```

but I've had no luck in keeping the special character. Below is my code:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TABLE_NAME purge;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME
(
COL_1   STRING,
COL_2   STRING,
COL_3   STRING,
COL_4   STRING,
COL_5   STRING,
COL_6   STRING,
COL_7   STRING,
COL_8   STRING,
COL_9   STRING,
COL_10  STRING,
COL_11  STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE 
LOCATION '/location/' 
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");

LOAD DATA INPATH '/location/' INTO TABLE TABLE_NAME;
```

Would anyone know any solutions to keeping the special characters in the table upload?

Edit:
Output of:

```
select "${system:file.encoding}";
```

gave me "UTF-8"

Answer (score 0):

This isn't my answer. A colleague was able to help so this is her solution so credit goes to her but I think its important to know for future reference. The text file was ANSI-encoded so she suggested putting in the following line in between the create table command and the load data statement above:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('serialization.encoding'='CP1252');
```